# How do I find if a specific train (RE60) carries bicycles during morning rush hour?

Tags: trains, germany, bicycles

I'm trying to find out if I can bring a bicycle during the morning rush hour on [RE60](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/traininfo.exe/dn/397650/359350/367834/51367/80?) (Frankfurt-Mannheim), and if yes, whether I need to buy a ticket.  This train is run by the DB Regio train company as part of the RMV transit association.

[RMV notes](https://www.rmv.de/c/de/fahrkarten/regeln/wichtige-tarifinformationen/fahrradmitnahme/):

> Verkehrsunternehmen können die Fahrradmitnahme zu bestimmten Zeiten einschränken oder auch bestimmte Züge und Busse von der Fahrradmitnahme ausschließen.

Which means that transport companies can limit the ability to bring bicycles or exclude certain trains and buses completely.

[DB Regio notes](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/fahrrad/bahn_und_bike_hessen.shtml):

> Die Fahrradmitnahme ist in den Verkehrsverbünden unterschiedlich geregelt. So gibt es in einigen Verkehrsverbünden Sperrzeiten für die Fahrrad mitnahme, um die im Berufsverkehr gefüllten Züge nicht zusätzlich zu belasten. Außerdem weichen die Preise für die Fahrradmitnahme in Verbünden in der Regel von den Tarifen der Deutschen Bahn ab.

which means that the rules for bicycles depend on the transport association, that some transit associations limit certain times for carrying bicycles or exclude certain trains completely, and that prices are different.

In the DB planner it just says *Fahrradmitnahme begrenzt möglich*, meaning it is limited, which could technically mean the limit is zero.  It doesn't say anything about payment.

This [particular train](https://www.rmv.de/c/de/linien-netze/fahrzeuge/regionalzuege/twindexx-vario-doppelstock-elektrotriebzuege/twindexx-vario-doppelstock-elektrotriebzug-main-neckar-ried/) has 12 or 18 places for bicycles, but those could still be blocked during rush hour.

DB refers to RMV and RMV refers to DB and I am little wiser.  How can I find out the specific rules applying to this specific train?

Comment: 'Fahrradmitnahme begrenzt möglich' is the standard disclaimer for trains with so called multipurpose compartments. You can not reserve a place for your bicycle and when the compartment is full, you may be denied to bring your bicycle. Baby strollers and wheel chairs usually have priority.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo In general, I know.  In any case, there is no guarantee for bringing the bicycle.  But the system knows the timetable.  Would it still state this if the train at a particular time was always blocked due to running between 06:00 and 09:00?

Comment: Probably, but it might depend on the region. The rules for bicycle transport are divergent and confusing and as you found out, it is not easy to tell what goes and what goes not. Here in Munich, it is not allowed to bring bicycles in local trains (S-Bahn) between 6:00 and 9:00 on working days, but the DB travel planner is not aware of that and show the same remark (Fahrradmitnahme begrenzt möglich) for these trains. Here, it is however allowed to bring bicycles in regional trains (RB/RE) between 6am and 9am.

Comment: While not being an answer, in this particular constallation, as RB Regio is operating the trains, it is relatively safe to assume that they would have put additional restrictions on bicyle transportation beyond the ones imposed by the RMV into their booking system. So if I were the OP, I would risk it. In any case, there is no guarantee that there is enough space for your bicycle on the train.

Comment: @DCTLib I know there is never such a guarantee (close to guarantee only with reservation, which there is only for some specific trains); I have a backup plan that will make me ~5 minutes late at my destination.  Anyway, I have contacted RMV through their online form and will see if they have a useful answer (I could not find an online contact for DB Regio).

Answer (score 2):

This is a local train, so given space is available on the train on the actual day of travel, you can take your bicycle. The space is limited so it could fill up, which is why there is a notice on the timetable to that respect.

Whether you need to pay for your bicycle depends on the local regulations, but these are always the same regardless of what time your trip is. If you don’t have to buy a bike ticket at 8 p.m. you don’t have to buy one at 8 a.m. either.

Comment: [*Der Radtransport ist von Montag bis Freitag vor 6 und nach 9 Uhr sowie an Samstagen, Sonn- und Feiertagen ganztägig kostenfrei möglich. Werktags zwischen 6 und 9 Uhr ist dagegen ein Fahrradticket nötig*](https://www.canyon.com/de-de/blog-content/fahrrad-ratgeber/fahrradmitnahme-bahn/b21092021.html) for Baden-Württemberg, which is where Mannheim is located (this is not an authoritative source, but I've heard the same before).